# jQuery Ajax request (CORS) returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, cross-domain

This is my first attempt at making a cross-domain Ajax request to an API. I'm using jQuery to make the call and am trying to place certain items from the return onto the page.

Here's the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://magicseaweed.com/api/APIKEY/forecast/?spot_id=665',
    contentType: "text/plain",
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
    },
    success: function(data) {
            timestamp = data.localTimestamp;
            alert(timestamp);
    },
    error: function() {
            alert("aw crap");
    }
});
```

Here's the response:

```
[{
    timestamp: 1366902000,
    localTimestamp: 1366902000,
    issueTimestamp: 1366848000,
    fadedRating: 0,
    solidRating: 0,
    swell: {
        minBreakingHeight: 1,
        absMinBreakingHeight: 1.06,
        maxBreakingHeight: 2,
        absMaxBreakingHeight: 1.66,
        unit: "ft",
        components: {
             combined: {
             height: 1.1,
             period: 14,
             direction: 93.25,
             compassDirection: "W"
        },
        primary: {
            height: 1,
            period: 7,
            direction: 83.37,
            compassDirection: "W"
        },
        secondary: {
            height: 0.4,
            period: 9,
            direction: 92.32,
            compassDirection: "W"
        },
        tertiary: {
            height: 0.3,
            period: 13,
            direction: 94.47,
            compassDirection: "W"
        }
    }
}]
```

Currently, I'm just trying to get the timestamp string to show in an alert box.

`alert(timestamp);` is returning as undefined. Where's my error?

Comment: what's the output of `alert(data)`, or even better `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` - nvm, just saw your data structure. @Abdennour TOUMI answer is right

Comment: It looks like the response is an array. Have you tried `data[0].localTimestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        timestamp = data[0].localTimestamp;
```

not

```
        timestamp = data.localTimestamp;
```

Because the response is an array with one item `[{...}]`